# Full Wave Rectifier and 7805 Regulator

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, full-bridge

I have make a full wave rectifier and aimed to obtained +9V, -9V and +5V DC from an AC transformer (I have  diplayed output of transformer only as AC1 and AC2) as i have shown below.

[image]

However, when i connect the +5V output and +9V output together, i have observed a significant decrease on the voltage level on both. I am condisering to change the configuration like one below. Do you think this will overcome the voltage level decrease problem? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a centre-tapped transformer, with the centre connected to the earth (between C1 and C4)? Otherwise this wo'nt work (unless you attach the load between the - and + outputs), because your ground would be floating.

Comment: Also, C1 and C4 will probably need to be much larger; search for how to calculate the size of a rectification smoothing capacitor.

Comment: Your GND node is (almost completely) isolated. It must somehow be connected to the transformer (AC1, AC2). See Transistor's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJvUvz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Dual supply from centre-tapped transformer. (b) Dual supply from single secondary transformer. (c) Re-using your bridge rectifier to create the (b) circuit.*

If you don't have a centre-tapped transformer you could modify your circuit as shown in Figure 1b. Note that C3 will now only get topped-up every positive half-cycle and C4 every negative half-cycle. You may need to almost double the C values to hold enough charge between cycles.

Since you already have a bridge rectifier you can use it to form D1 and D2. Draw it out using diodes instead of the bridge and you should see that you can double-up the diodes by addding the grey wire.

Answer (score 0):

Do as Transistor says.

I'm just adding this because the 1µF capacitors after the diode bridge are much too small. You need a lot more capacitance there.

i = C dv/dt

If the capacitor is charged every 10ms by the diodes, then dt=10ms.

If you draw a current of 1A, then i=1A

If the voltage on the caps is allowed to drop by 3V between each recharging pulse, then C=i dt/dv = 3300µF is the minimum value.

7809 drops 2V so we know it requires 11V minimum at the input, but the transformer's internal resistance and how much voltage it will deliver at its rated current depends on its VA rating, which you don't provide. If it's a small 12V transformer, a cap between 2200µF and 4700µF will work fine. If you need less current, the value scales down accordingly.